# How to make wlscirep suppress abstract?

Tags: overleaf, abstract, wlscirep

I wish to modify the following code so as to stop the abstract from appearing in the generated pdf file. Simply commenting out the three abstract related lines gave an error.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}

\title{Title}

\author[1,*]{Author Name}
\affil[1]{Author Affiliation}
\affil[*]{Author Email}    

\begin{abstract}
My kingdom for a suppressed abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

This uses [this overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns#.WaeeQRdBqkB).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The document class you are using requires an abstract, and doesn't include an option to not print an abstract at all. So you have to go into the code of the class, find where the abstract is printed out, and redefine those commands in your document.

The original lines of code of the class are:

```
%
% custom title page 
%
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@title\par}%
\vskip10pt
{\raggedright\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@author\par}
\vskip18pt%
{%
\noindent
{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\color{color1}\large\sffamily\textbf{ABSTRACT}}}
}%
\vskip10pt
{%
\noindent
\colorbox{color2}{%
\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
\sffamily\small\textbf\\\theabstract
}%
}%
% \vskip18pt%
% \noindent
% \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
% {\color{color1}\keywordname\hspace*{1em}} \@keywords%
%}%
}%
\vskip25pt%
}%
}%
```

So in the following example, I redefined the `\@maketitle` macro to not print out the abstract:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author[1,*]{Author Name}
\affil[1]{Author Affiliation}
\affil[*]{Author Email}    

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\vskip-36pt%
{\raggedright\sffamily\bfseries\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont \@title\par}%
\vskip10pt
{\raggedright\sffamily\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont  \@author\par}
\vskip25pt%
}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to custom 'Author Name' not being bold faced? ```\normalfont{\@author}``` is not working

Comment: ```\renewcommand*{\Affilfont}{\normalsize\normalfont}``` and ```\renewcommand*{\Authfont}{\normalfont}``` do the trick